# Javascript - set text box value to null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make changes in an existing script but I am stuck at a point.
I don't want to populate value of a textbox on change event, so I tried setting its value to null.

```
    var rateDescLst = document.getElementsByName('bsegListTr');
    var rateDescLen = rateDescLst.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rateDescLen ; i++) { 

        var val = rateDescLst[i].childNodes[11].innerHTML;

        if(rateDescLst[i].childNodes[11].innerHTML=='PER PROPRTR/PRTNRSHP'){  
        //document.getElementsByName('censusUpdValue').value='';
        rateDescLst[i].childNodes[7].value="";
        }
    }
```

I tried setTextValue() , nodeValue and many other options, but none of them worked. I believe til If condition everything is correct, I tried innerHTML = '' but it removed text box also from UI.
I want to set null to rateDescLst[i].childNodes[7]

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You should use ```.innerHTML = null ```

Comment: It is removing text box from the UI. I need a blank box.

Comment: If `innerHTML = ""` removed the entire *element*, then `rateDescLst[i].childNodes[7]` is a *container* of the textbox. You need to select the textbox itself and set its `.value`

Comment: Better if you can paste some HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('censusUpdValue').setAttribute("value", "");
```

This code in place of the commented part should help make your textbox null.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<input type="text" value="hello" name="group"><br>
<input type="text" value="hello" name="group"><br>
<input type="text" value="hello" name="group"><br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("group");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].setAttribute("value","");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!